# HTML figure element will offset my image?

Tags: html, css

Just looking for a reason as to why my image becomes offset when I use a figure tag.

For instance I have a basic tile class as follows:

```css
.tile {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 400px;
  border: #000 solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <figure>
    <img src="example" alt="example" width="300">
  </figure>
</div>
```

When I remove the figure element, my image positions itself as I expect. But with the figure tag, my image is always offset to the right no matter what I try to do. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By *default*, the [`<figure>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) has the following CSS declarations:

```
figure {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

This is causing the offset that you see.

You can specify your own [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) to override these if you desire, as can be seen in the following:

```css
.tile {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 400px;
  border: #000 solid 2px;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://yari-demos.prod.mdn.mozit.cloud/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure/favicon-192x192.png" alt="example" width="50">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I looked at that same page you linked regarding figure, and I did not see the default declarations. Thank you for this!